# How to anchor ImageView to layout

Tags: android, xml, imageview, anchor

I'm trying to anchor `ImageView` to layout as below

[image]

We can anchor `FloatingActionButton` but how to `anchor` a `Imageview`

I'm not using `CoordinatorLayout`. i'm using `LinearLayout`

How can i do that

Comment: you can anchor easily if you would use`ConstraintLayout`

Comment: `LinearLayout` doesn't have anchors.

Comment: You can achieve this by relative layout

Comment: I use dirty trick to acheive these type of view , just keep both views in linear layout and give negative margin  to move 1 view over other .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_account_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolView_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView_account_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear_account_input_details"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="NILU"
                                android:textSize="30sp" />

                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                                android:hint="Enter Email" />

                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                                android:hint="Enter Paasword" />


                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                android:text="Login" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="This is demo" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```